# Using GREP and regular expressions to search for multiple strings

Tags: regex, grep

I have spent the past few hours to trying to get a regular expression string right and have had no luck. The strings function would be to search through a file list and pull the ones which have any of the following in them:`(OL####,DE####,DEA####,OLA####)`. Thus far I have gotten the following to sort of work.

```
grep  "\<[DE\b|DEA\b|OL\b|OLA\b]\+[0-9]"
```

However it still finds things such as "E1" and pulls those lines out. What am I missing? I am very new to regular expressions and am trying to learn as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep -oE '\b(OL|DE|DEA|OLA)[0-9]+\b' file
```

Comment: Your answer got it, thank you so much, although I had to remove the -o to get the full line like I wanted. Most excited ive been all day when I saw it only pull up the list of entries I was looking for.

Comment: Yes, `-o` prints only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace your square brackets with round ones and remove the `+`:

```
grep -P "<(DE|DEA|OL|OLA)[0-9]"
```

Also note that angle brackets don't need escaping. I'm assuming you intended to have the `<` there, since it's not in your example strings.

Comment: I tried to use parenthesis early on however then and after trying your code, it gave me zero results in the output file.

Comment: Does your file have the angle brackets in it? If not, remove them from the regex. Also, I forgot to include the `-P` to use PCRE. `-E` would also work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) inside of a character class. A character class defines a set of characters. Saying — "match one character specified by the class". Use a [grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) construct instead:

I would try the following to match the lines:

```
grep -E '\b(DEA?|OLA?)[0-9]+'
```

If you only want the substring, use the following:

```
grep -Eo '\b(DEA?|OLA?)[0-9]+'
```